# ADB Devices crash on mac os Sierra ! :(

Tags: android, macos, adb, macos-sierra

I'm having trouble testing the apps I'm developing on android devices, I'm using the macbook pro updated with mac osx Sierra, someone would know of some solution, I type `adb devices` in the terminal and it gives me the white screen and reboots the mac.

```
Anonymous UUID:       

Sun Jan  1 23:13:06 2017

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff801fe05ead): Kernel trap at 0xffffff8020292447, type 13=general protection, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x00000000001a1000, CR3: 0x000000006bd38000, CR4: 0x0000000000002660
RAX: 0xc0ffee43a3a626d2, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0xffffff8031f58c08, RDX: 0x0000000000000001
RSP: 0xffffff912a2d3ca0, RBP: 0xffffff912a2d3cd0, RSI: 0x0000000000000005, RDI: 0xffffff8031c15200
R8:  0x000000000000ffff, R9:  0x0000000000000001, R10: 0x0000000000000010, R11: 0x0000000000000001
R12: 0x0000000000000000, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff8031f58c00, R15: 0xffffff8031c15200
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff8020292447, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x00000000001a1000, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x1, PL: 0, VF: 0

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810067ddf0 : 0xffffff801fcf211c 
0xffffff810067de70 : 0xffffff801fe05ead 
0xffffff810067e050 : 0xffffff801fca3743 
0xffffff810067e070 : 0xffffff8020292447 
0xffffff912a2d3cd0 : 0xffffff8020293372 
0xffffff912a2d3d20 : 0xffffff80202ed29d 
0xffffff912a2d3d70 : 0xffffff801fdc4dc2 
0xffffff912a2d3dc0 : 0xffffff801fcf737c 
0xffffff912a2d3e20 : 0xffffff801fcd3fe1 
0xffffff912a2d3e70 : 0xffffff801fce8397 
0xffffff912a2d3f00 : 0xffffff801fdf1d8c 
0xffffff912a2d3fb0 : 0xffffff801fca3d18 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: adb

Mac OS version:
16C67

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.3.0: Thu Nov 17 20:23:58 PST 2016; root:xnu-3789.31.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 
Kernel slide:     0x000000001fa00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801fc00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801fb00000
System model name: MacBookPro7,1 (Mac-F222BEC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3747920886441
last loaded kext at 2828004028446: com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard   197 (addr 0xffffff7fa2a44000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 1611593635040: com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard  197 (addr 0xffffff7fa219e000, size 40960)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  5.0.20
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  5.0.20
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 5.0.20
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 5.0.20
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    6.0.3
com.avg.Antivirus.OnAccess.kext 2016.0
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   359.2.14
com.apple.filesystems.exfat 1.4
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.14
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    127
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   278.56
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    5.0.2f4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   278.56
com.apple.GeForceTesla  10.0.2
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 5.0.2f4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.9.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.15
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  366.30.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  340
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  252
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 252
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 404.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  295.20.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  326
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 219.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   172
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   219.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  197
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   5.0.2f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   197
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.13.78
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   153.3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   10.0.2
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 278.56
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   5.0.2f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  5.0.2f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   5.0.2f4
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    10.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.7
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 278.56
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 278.56
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   205.11
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   513.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    513.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.1
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 258
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   394.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  131.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   394.30.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBOHCIPCI    1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBOHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.1
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 444.30.5
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM MBP71.0039.B0E, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2,4 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.62f7
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341344758334D314131303636433720
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341344758334D314131303636433720
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.2f4, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: KINGSTON SUV400S37240G, 240,06 GB
Serial ATA Device: ST9250315ASG, 250,06 GB
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: USB Bus
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: HID-compliant Mouse
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: DFU Loader
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Card Reader
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
Revision eac51f2bb6a8-android

Comment: What form would you expect a solution to take when you haven't posted anything that can be fixed?

Comment: Sorry, the problem is when adb is running is restarting the machine, but if this question is in the wrong place please forgive me!